# Allowing a Post to show datetime without user input (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I want to be able to show a datetime stamp ( I want it to appear like - "Posted 5 days ago" ), but i dont want the date field to appear when an user is making a post.

I just want to post to add it automatically. Any help? (Im just learning Rails so its all new to me...)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Forum Application I did this:

```
<td class="right"> 
    <% if forum.most_recent_post %><%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now forum.most_recent_post.last_post_at %> ago by <%= link_to forum.most_recent_post.user.login, "/users/#{forum.most_recent_post.last_poster_id}" %>
    <% else %> no posts <% end %>
</td>
```

Here `<%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now forum.most_recent_post.last_post_at %>` ago by "username" so, you may try this. I think that can work in this scenario too. Just use `distance_of_time_in_words_to_now post.time` here post.time is the time when user made a post.

Comment: Hi I tried the code but it says that I have an undefined method for "distance_of_time_in_word_to_now" any help?

Comment: Nvm. I ended up adding this: <%= link_to "#{distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(post.created_at)} ago", post %> and it worked perfectly!...

Comment: @ChrisBedoya - In my case the above code was working so, I pasted that :P, well that's good if it's working in the way you have mentioned in comment,cheers... :)

Comment: Thanks! The "Nvm" was meant for my first comment. I appreciate the help!